# Express nodejs not inserting data using mongoose with form-data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

From last 2 weeks i am unable to post a data to insert into database using form-data it always shows 400 bad request here is my code
My **server.js**

```js
require('./db.js')
let express = require('express')
// let mongoose = require()
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
let routes = require('./routes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.set('port', 4000);

// app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.use('/api', routes);


app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.method, req.url);
    next();
})

let server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    let port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Connected Successfully at", + port);
});
```

here is my **Controller** file code

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let cat = mongoose.model('Cat')


module.exports.addcat = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    cat.
        create({
        cat_name: req.body.cat_name,
        cat_description: req.body.cat_description

    },function(err, cate){
        if(err){
            console.log(" Error creating Hotel");
            res
                .status(400)
                .json(err)
        }else{
            console.log("Hotel created", cate);
            res
                .status(200)
                .json(cate);
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my schema file shop.models.js

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose')

let productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    prod_name : {
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    prod_description : {
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    prod_base_price : {
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    prod_tax : {
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    prod_final_price : {
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    prod_images : [Array],
    prod_discount : {
        type:Number,
        required:true
    }

})

let catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cat_name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    cat_description:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
})


mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);
```

this my routes file routes.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const ctrlCat = require('../controllers/cat.controller.js')



// Category Router
router
    .route('/cat')
    .get(ctrlCat.getcat)
    .post(ctrlCat.addcat);

router
    .route('/cat/:catid')
    .get(ctrlCat.getonecat)
    .put(ctrlCat.editonecat)
    .delete(ctrlCat.deletecat);

module.exports = router;
```

Please help me to out always shows this error

```
{
    "errors": {
        "cat_name": {
            "message": "Path `cat_name` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "cat_name"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "cat_name",
            "$isValidatorError": true
        },
        "cat_description": {
            "message": "Path `cat_description` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "cat_description"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "cat_description",
            "$isValidatorError": true
        }
    },
    "_message": "Cat validation failed",
    "message": "Cat validation failed: cat_name: Path `cat_name` is required., cat_description: Path `cat_description` is required.",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

and 400 bad request i am unable to understand where m doing wrong please help me out m stuck here from last 2 weeks When ever i send my data using form-data it show this error other wise it working fine with urlencoded and raw. Currently m testing over postman. I tried this with react too but shows same issue

Comment: from this error, it seems you have a `Model` named `Hotel`. Which has `name` as a field, which is set as `required`. Somewhere in your code the data insertion is trying to happen on `Hotel` Model but it's failing due to `required` validation @Akshay

Comment: but i also remove that required but its not getting data. When i remove required it sends blank data is there any problem with code

Comment: @AkshaySharma Drop collection and try again.

Comment: same output @rahulsharma

Comment: uncomment `// app.use(bodyParser.json());` and check whats content-type in request. make sure it's application/json

Comment: i tried even after doing uncoment it shows same error  and content type is same application/json

Comment: even after doing editing with this it shows this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
                <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use appropriate middleware to parse the form data, so that req.body will contain the form data. So uncommenting

> app.use(bodyParser.json());

should do the trick.

Furthermore you should export your cat schema.

> module.exports = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);

and require in the control file using.

> const cat = require( ' /path/to/cat ' );

It appears that json response after saving the new cat object somehow produces extra character. You can try manually editing it out. Somewhat like this

```
module.exports.addcat = function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
cat.
    create({
    cat_name: req.body.cat_name,
    cat_description: req.body.cat_description

},function(err, cate){
    if(err){
        console.log(" Error creating Hotel");
        res
            .status(400)
            .json(err)
    }else{
        console.log("Hotel created", cate);
            //manual editing
            var firstChar = cate.substring(0, 1);
            var firstCharCode = cate.charCodeAt(0);
            if (firstCharCode == 65279) {
                console.log('First character "' + firstChar + '" (character code: ' + firstCharCode + ') is invalid so removing it.');
                cate = cate.substring(1);
            }

            var parsedJson = JSON.parse(cate);
            console.log('parsedJson: ', parsedJson);
            res
                .status(200)
                .json(cate);
    }
})
}
```

If the same issue appears some where else then use this there too. Thanks!

Comment: it shows the same error `Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` please help me out find out what's the syntax error

Comment: i think its not problem of any produce of extra character it shows same issue